# ValueError while finding the largest element in nested arrays

Tags: python

Currently I am working on a project in which I need to find out the coordinates as well as the value of the largest element inside a large array (say 500 X 5).

So I used this command to find the maximum value of the array:

```
y= max(arr) #here arr is my huge array.
```

But I encountered this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Can anybody tell me, what should I do to rectify this error?

EDIT:

To be specific, my array *arr* contains 3 rows and each row itself is an array of size 500 X 5.

Comment: Please provide some more information on this `arr`

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the list `arr` that you are using is nested, and doesn't have a flat structure. Since one of the element of the list is list in itself, it is causing the error.

Comment: Actually, if it is a 500x5 array, then **all** of its elements are lists.

Comment: @hspandher Yes i have edited the question please check, thanks!

Comment: If all the elements are list, what exactly do you want to find - the list with the maximum sum, or the maximum number in all lists?

Comment: @hspandher The major list is A and there are several lists inside this major list say a,b,c,d... These sub-lists are of size 365 X 500. So i need to find maximum element out of each sub-list of the major array. I hope I might have cleared your confusion now.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = max(max(max(column) for row in arr for column in row)
```

will find the largest element.

Comment: I used this command which you have mentioned in this comment in the first line.
I used y= max(arr[ j ]) where j is the row number.
As i mentioned in the edit, each row in my array has another array.
So i used this command to get the max value of each array.
But got the same error as before. :(

Comment: So you have one more level of nesting. In the future, try to describe your problem **precisely**.

Comment: yes i am sorry for the confusion. But as for now, what might be the solution?

Comment: This happened to work with a smaller array. But when  i used it on the actual one, it showed the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can first flatten your array `arr` into a list via `arr.flatten()` from numpy function. Then call the `max(arr.flatten())` to get the largest element.

#### Edit

An example is following: Let's assume that you have a multi-dimensional array 'arr' as python nested-list.

```
import numpy as np

table = np.asarray(arr)
max_arr=max(table.flatten())
print(max_arr)
```

Comment: How do you do that? Can you please give me an example to work with this syntax? Sorry i am new to python.

Comment: `numpy` is a module; you need to install it and then `import numpy` in your program to use its functions.